# How to know through JavaScript when the user starts or stops a video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, events, youtube

On a page with an embedded Flash video (from YouTube in an `<iframe/>`), is it possible to be notified through JavaScript when the user starts or stops playing a video?

As far as I know, events raised on Flash level are not propagated to the container page, so it is not possible to do that. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[YouTube JavaScript Player API Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

If the player is in an iframe you will have no access to it due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)
If you can, you should embed the player directly in your page and look for what you need in the [api](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html).

A quick glance found this:

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
  ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
  ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
}

function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
   alert("Player's new state: " + newState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) within Flash to call a javascript function each time the user starts or stops the video.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [youtube api](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html) for manipulating movie, For example: make some overlay that will control movie, by capturing *click* events.